# What are the four shades of grey on the FR24 map?

Tags: flightradar24

I just noticed the sunset border on Flightradar24 maps. I wonder: what are the 4 shades of grey, and why are they relevant? Why not just show one?
[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that a question called "3 stages of twilight" is inherently different from "four shades of grey on the FR24 map". First, because I need to know there are stages of twilight and, second, because I need to know that FlightRadar shows the stages of twilight. Then I can find that question and get the information I need. So, instead of calling this question a duplicate, it might have been more relevant to answer "these are the twilight stages" and point to the other question. As WPNSGuy did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varying levels of daylight, going into night.

This previous question goes into much more detail, and it may indeed be related to the aeronautical definitions as day turns into night.

[What are these 3 stages of twilight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90380/what-are-these-3-stages-of-twilight)

Comment: Upvote for being correct, but there might be a deeper meaning...  For example, there is sunset, nautical twilight, etc. that have distinct meanings.  Could it be related to these definitions?  I don't have time or motivation to research, just throwing it out there...  ;)

Comment: @Michael Hall - Looking through the FR24 glossary and FAQ, and searching for "day", "night", "grey", "gray", I see nothing related to the varying shades of grey. Of course, I may be just missing it.