# Flying Considerations during an Eclipse?

Tags: faa-regulations, visual-flight-rules, eclipse

[August 21, 2017 will see a total eclipse of the sun](http://www.eclipse2017.org/2017/path_through_the_US.htm) across large sections of the United States, generally between about 10a.m. and 2p.m. (depending on location and timezone)

**If one is flying during the eclipse, are there considerations, other than sudden transitions to darkness and then to light, that should be taken into account?**

Do Pilots flying during this time need to be Night Current?
Can time logged during the eclipse be logged as Night Conditions?

Comment: Good point; I edited the question to ask about other considerations such as temperatures and winds.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13377/62)

Comment: @kevin The other question is about the UK, this one is US

Comment: @Pondlife that's true but the accepted answer provides the US regulations as well.

Comment: @fooot Yes, I'm just not a fan of "that other question has the answer even though it's actually a different question". In this case it's probably reasonable enough (the other question does mention the US, although it's secondary) but it's the principle of the thing. Maybe I'm overthinking it :-)

Comment: Hmm... In its current state, this does not seem like a duplicate to me. The answer to the other question answers _part_ of this question, but not all of it. Similarly, there's information that would be relevant here that would not answer the other question (temperature, wind, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

> Do Pilots flying during this time need to be Night Current?

No, that time does not fall within what the FAA considers "night"

[The FAA defines night currency in FAA FAR 61.57](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?pitd=20170321&node=se14.1.61_157&rgn=div8)

> FAA FAR 61.57
>
> (b) Night takeoff and landing experience. (1) Except as provided in
>   paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command
>   of an aircraft carrying passengers **during the period beginning 1
>   hour after sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise**, unless within
>   the preceding 90 days that person has made at least three takeoffs and
>   three landings to a full stop during the period beginning 1 hour after
>   sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise, and—

---

> Can time logged during the eclipse be logged as Night Conditions?

Nope, same reason as above it does not fall in what the FAA considers "night".

Comment: So if the Sun were to suddenly disappear during the day, then despite being in eternal night, the FAA would call it "day" because the sun never set? `:D`

Comment: @NickT I guarantee you that, if that ever happens, FAA regulations will be the least weird thing going on!

Comment: To log night time, the flight needs to occur between evening civil twilight and the beginning of morning civil twilight, as published in the Air Almanac, converted to local time.  - FAR §1.1